# Do iPhone developers qualify for ADC hardware discount

Tags: iphone

If so, what do you need to provide online and in a real apple shop. I am gonna check it myself, but am asking for a heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need an ADC Select (or Premier) Membership (or a one-time student developer membership) to qualify for the ADC discounts.

However, at least in the US, [Select Membership](http://developer.apple.com/products/membership.html) is only $499 for a year, which was lower than the discount when I joined and bought my laptop.

Details are [here.](http://developer.apple.com/membership/hardware.html)

---

More info: There is also an [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/), but this doesn't provide access to hardware discounts.  The $99/$299 subscription for this provides access to the iPhone SDK and pre-releases of iPhone's 3.0 OS, plus the ability to distribute programs developed on iTunes in the Music Store.  Unfortunately, hardware discounts are only for Apple Developer Connection members, and (at least previously), only apply to Mac hardware, and not iPhones + accessories.

---

In response to the comments about hardware discounts... Apple doesn't hide this:

For comparison: The [Standard US online store price](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro?mco=MTE3MDE) for a MacBook Pro is $2799. (now)

The [ADC price](http://store.apple.com/us_adc_38839/browse/home/shop_mac/family/macbook_pro?mco=MTE3MDE) is only $2239, which more than pays for the $499 membership.

However, there are some differences - the ADC version of the hardware doesn't have the same warranties as the retail version, is supposed to be for development, etc.  See the fine print for details.  And I was incorrect - the iPod Touch is discounted on the ADC store ($359 vs $399).

Comment: Thanks, reason I ask this is, I saw this: http://developer.apple.com/, which lists iphone stuff for adc, so thought it might apply for that too.

Comment: See my updated response - this doesn't provide hardware discounts, but does provide SDK access plus beta access to new iPhone OS releases (3.0 beta), and distribution

Comment: Thanks, I bet that would also include the ipod touch, right?

Comment: I believe so - ipod touch uses the same sdk as the iphone...

Comment: Thanks, actually I meant the hardward discount for the ipod :), since you said not for iPhones.

Comment: How much discount would I get with the 499 membership from a mac book pro?

Answer (score 6):

From March 2010 the new Mac Developers Program replaces the old ADC Premier and ADC Select programs.  The new Mac Developers Program (US$99/year) does not include any hardware discounts.  Existing ADC Premier and ADC Select members can continue to use their existing discounts until their membership expires.

From the [FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/programs/adcbenefits/faq.html):

> **What is the ADC Hardware Purchase Program and who is eligible for hardware discounts through the ADC Hardware Purchase Program?**
>
> The ADC Hardware Purchase Program is only available to existing paid ADC Members and it allows them to purchase, at a discount, a limited number of hardware systems to use for development and testing. ADC Premier members receive ten (10) ADC Hardware Discounts each membership year and ADC Select members receive one (1) ADC Hardware Discount each membership year. Prices, product offerings, and program terms are subject to change at Apple’s discretion. Prices for particular product purchases are those in effect at the time of shipment. All products are accompanied by Apple’s standard limited hardware warranty for those products. Purchases made outside of the ADC Hardware Purchase Program will not be re-booked or credited at developer pricing. There are no refunds on items purchased through the ADC Hardware Purchase Program. **There are no hardware discounts associated with the new Mac Developer Program.**

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the store is no longer there :(.